# IOS: AVAudioPlayer management memory

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have this method to play an mp3:

```
- (void) playSound:(NSString*)sound{

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                      sound];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];
    [player prepareToPlay]; 
    [player play];  
}
```

everytime I call this method I get a new string "sound" and then I must alloc everytime this AVAudioplayer "player"; I want release it when I stop it or when it finish...is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below instruction

yourViewController.h

```
 @interface yourViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

yourViewController.m file for add function

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
 //play finished
}
```

Declare the AVAudioPlayer Object below code

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
                                                                fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                                                 pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL]; 

    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0.0f;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AVAudioPlayerDelegate.

It has the methods audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: and audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:error: that should let you do what you want.